# Portrait video converted to Landscape in AWS Elemental Mediaconvert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, http-live-streaming, video-on-demand

I'm using AWS 'Elemental MediaConvert' service to get the HLS format of the uploaded video. We are using this as Video-On-Demand service. Everything works fine. Video that is been uploaded in 's3-input' bucket will taken by lambda service and processed by boto3 elemental mediaconvert client. Out of the video will be stored in 's3-output' bucket. One problem is Portrait videos are appearing in Landscape mode in 's3-output' bucket and also when HLS url is played in mobile/browser.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use the latest version of boto3 if you use it at all. Anyways 
Add `"Rotate": "AUTO"` to `VideoSelector` in inputs. In this case, EMC will try to automatically rotate the video based on metadata if it's available.

These links were really useful for me:

- List https://www.mandsconsulting.com/lambda-functions-with-newer-version-of-boto3-than-available-by-default/
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mediaconvert.html

Answer (score 0):

Well... In your place here is what I'd do... I'll go to the last "job"... Go to the "output" section. Then go to the output formats sub-sections... and set the size of the desired output **Manually**.

I don't think Elemental MediaConvert has presets for vertical video. It's a pretty new (awesome) product.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS, "If your input video container is .mov or .mp4 and your input has rotation metadata, you can choose Automatic to have the service rotate your video according to the rotation specified in the metadata."

The default rotation mode is "None" so it takes all videos back to landscape but when you set it to default, it checks the metadata of the video and sees that it is meant to be portrait, then it rotates it to portrait automatically.

That works for me.
[image]

You can also set rotation to specific degrees for other use cases, You can specify a clockwise rotation of 0, 90, 180, or 270 degrees.